# How to set the session setting in new window

Tags: php, mysql

I have created one login  using PHP and MYSQL.

If login the page, it will go to the new page.

My Problem:
Once logout my login page its again showing the new page itself,but I don't want to show that page after I logout

```
?php 
  session_start();


  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
  }
  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: login.php");
  }
```

Comment: The code after calling header function is executed. You should add an `exit` statement after `header("location: ...")`

Comment: We tried to using exit functions. But did not working  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
   header('location:login.php');
   exit;
  }
  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
   session_destroy();
   unset($_SESSION['username']);
   header("location: login.php");
   exit;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
session_destroy();
sesion_write_close();
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); 
}
```

Here `session_destroy();` destroys all sessions created after successful login. On the other hand `sesion_write_close();` makes sure no further conflicting session shall be written after destroying the sessions and before redirecting the page to the defined location. However, it's a very basic but clear and effective logout guideline.

Comment: we tired this code. again same problem.  This code is added to index.php file.Its right?

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_SESSION);` and see if any session exists after you log out.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I don't know your directory structure. I assumed that you passed the key `logout` to query string. Is it in the query string or it's an object?